# Ngb rating max value dyamic change is not reflected in stars length

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

In ngb rating the max value dynamic change is not reflecting on the stars length. Two-way binding is happening in `[max]=""`. But the stars length is not changing.

```html
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate" [max]="maxValue"></ngb-rating>
<hr>
<pre>Rate: <b>{{currentRate}}</b></pre>

<button class="btn" (click)="addValue()">Add</button>
<span>{{maxValue}}</span>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-rating-basic',
  templateUrl: './rating-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdRatingBasic {
  currentRate = 8;
  maxValue = 5;

  addValue() {
    this.maxValue++;
  }
}
```

[image: Output screenshot]

Comment: Create [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Sam Joseph, may you please create an issue so that we would address this bug? 
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [the rating source code](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/rating/rating.ts), we clearly see that [the stars count is calculated only on ngOnInit](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/rating/rating.ts#L183). As a workaround, I can only imagine forcing the rating to rerender using `*ngIf`:

```html
<ngb-rating *ngIf='showRating' [(rate)]="currentRate" [max]="maxValue"></ngb-rating>
<hr>
<pre>Rate: <b>{{currentRate}}</b></pre>

<button class="btn" (click)="addValue()">Add</button>
<span>{{maxValue}}</span>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-rating-basic',
  templateUrl: './rating-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdRatingBasic {
  currentRate = 8;
  maxValue = 5;
  showRating=true;

  addValue() {
    this.maxValue++;
    this.showRating=false;
    // timeout to wait for rating component to be hidden
    setTimeout(()=>{this.showRating=true}, 10);
  }
}
```